# Use of "purpose" in a question

Tags: phrases

During study Business-English I am wondering about the use of "purpose" in a "What" Question.

> **For what** purposes should this be ?
>
> **What** purposes should this be **for** ?

Are both sentences / questions correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/question-words/what) (see [here* also](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/questions-and-negative-sentences/questions-wh-questions)) both are correct.

> "**What** purposes should this be **for**?" - correct ✅
>
> "**For what**" purposes should this be?" correct. ✅

But the first is considered as informal style, especially in speaking, the preposition may be separated and placed at the end of the question clause.

But according to [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/ending-sentences-with-prepositions)

> "**What** purposes should this be **for**?" - correct ✅
>
> "**For what**" purposes should this be?" incorrect. ❌

It's a little bit weird since this dictionary by itself states there that "There’s no necessity to ban prepositions from the end of sentences. Ending a sentence with a preposition is a perfectly natural part of the structure of modern English."

Anyway in fact people use both structures that you showed in your question.

*See also here in [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/question-words/what) (under the title: What...for?)

Comment: What would be the best academic phrasing ? EG. "What function is that for ?" or "What functions should our product ideas include ?"
Should also be fine, isn't it ?

Comment: Your tow examples are not equal for a comparison. (If you asked me for example about the differences of "What function is that for?" and "Is that function for what" then I would chose the first option.) Anyway both of your examples are grammatically correct. Did I answer your question or maybe you have something to make clearer?

Comment: At this stage of studying, where it is importent for me to get more and more confident with the phrasing of a sentence, answers like yours are very welcome and helpful.